# How do I fade between scenes when my player reaches a certain point

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer

I have made a 2d Platformer but when my player reaches the end of a level I want it to fade to the next level.

How can I have multiple scenes that each have one level and that fade in and out?

Load Scene -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator Switch;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)//I try to check for the checkpoint but failed
        {
            if (other.tag == "End") 
            {
                LoadNextLevel();
            }
            
        }
    }

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
        
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int LevelIndex)
    {
        Switch.SetTrigger("Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: [We have previous Q&A on this topic too](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+scene+fade) - what have you tried based on your research so far? Is there a particular step in the process you're stuck on?

Comment: @DMGregory how do I fade when I hit my end checkpoint. I have. a script that loads when I click the mouse but I want to change that

Comment: Looks like you should share the script you use to detect when the checkpoint has been hit, and the script you use to load the scene when you click the mouse, if you want help combining them.

Comment: up[dated question

Answer (score 0):

Make a shader transition in any shader language ([this website](https://gl-transitions.com/) is a great one) and before loading the next scene, activate the transition.

If the player enters the level (scene) then forward and backward when he exit.

You can use a raycast with a collider at the end of the level to know if you are at the end of the level or not.

Comment: Welcome to Game Dev Stack Exchange & thank you for contributing. The "forward and backward" part of your answer isn't immediately clear to me, could you elaborate on that part of your answer?

Comment: For "forward" I meant the normal direction of the shader and "backward" would be the opposite direction, for example: the normal would be that the circles opens up in the shader when entering a level but would close when exiting a level.

Answer (score 0):

You've nested your `OnTriggerEnter2D` method *inside* your `Update` method:

```
void Update()
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)//I try to check for the checkpoint but failed
    {
        if (other.tag == "End") 
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
        
    }
}
```

That means the method named `OnTriggerEnter2D` exists *only* when Unity is running your `Update`, and can only be called from *inside* the `Update` method. When Unity is doing the physics simulation step and handling trigger events (which happens *before* `Update` is called), if it checks this script for an `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, it won't find one.

**Lesson:** *never* nest Unity message events inside another method. 99.9% of the time, *all* your methods should be directly within the class, not wedged inside one another.

Secondly, you'll want to add a flag or something to prevent the loading coroutine from firing multiple times over the second that it's active, something like...

```
public class Loader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator sceneChange;
    private Coroutine _loadInProgress;
 
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // Don't need to check for "End" tag if this is on
        // your "End" object itself. You could however
        // check if the player is the one that hit
        // the endpoint, if other things can.
        // if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }                
    }

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        if (_loadInProgress == null) {
            int nextLevel = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;
            _loadInProgress = StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(nextLevel));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int LevelIndex)
    {
        sceneChange.SetTrigger("Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelIndex);
        _loadInProgress = null;
    }
}
```

You might also want to use `LoadSceneAsync` to start the load while your animation is in progress, that way you can minimize any stutter or delay at the end of the animation.

Comment: do I need a 2d collider on my checkpoint sprite cause when I do it does nothing and what code does it need

Comment: In order to fire an `OnTriggerEnter2D` message, both objects involved in a collision need a 2D collider attached. At least one of them needs to have a `Rigidbody2D` attached, and at least one of the colliders involved needs to have the `isTrigger` box checked.

Comment: my player has a rigidbody and the end sprite has a 2d box collider which has is trigger ticked

Comment: And which of these objects is tagged "End"?

Comment: my end checkpoint sprite cause my player  is tagged player

Comment: Is this script on your player or on your end sprite?

Comment: on the level loader game object

Comment: Put this script on your end sprite object, and remove the check for the tag "End" (you don't need to check for a tag if this script is ON the tagged object)

Comment: It does nothing

Comment: Put a debug log method inside OnTriggerEnter2D - does it get called? Do you see any other errors or warnings inside your console?

Comment: no message comes up

Comment: Then we have some possibilities: 1. The objects are not colliding - check that their colliders overlap and that they are in physics layers that are set to collide with one another. 2. A Rigidbody2D is missing, or the trigger checkbox is not checked. 3. This script is not on the same object as one of the colliders involved in the collision. 4. You didn't remove the tag check. Double-check each of those cases.

Comment: So if I put my trap script on the finish I die and respawn so I think its the level loader code that's the problem